# tikz, specifying xy coordinate by xyz, why the difference

Tags: tikz-pgf

I specify the coordinate (x,y) by (x,y,0).  The two blue line segments should have equal length, but there is a far difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red]          (-2cm,-2cm) grid (3,2cm);
    \draw[blue]         (0,0,0) -- (0, 0.71cm, 0);
    \draw[blue, thick]         (1,0,0) -- (1, 0.71cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: the blue line segments]

Comment: I do not know the exact reason, but it comes from `cm` in `(0, 0.71cm, 0)`. The default length of the y vector in 3D is 1cm. I guess it does not make sense to go 0.71cm*1cm = 0.71cm^2 up. In 2d when a length is given, the unit vector is not used. Maybe `0.71cm` is converted to a number of `pt` (=20,12598).

Comment: It's getting multiplied by 28ish because of the use of coordinates using units, apparently. So you probably need to remove the `cm` when specifying coordinates in the xyz coordinate system. Alternatively, the answer to the linked question provides code which might allow you to hack the interpretation to catch the units. It's not that it doesn't make sense. It's that the handling of coordinates turns things into points before multiplying by the vector. So for each `cm`, you get 28ish (pts) and the 28ish then gets multiplied by the vector which is 1cm. So you get just over 28cm.

Comment: @hpekristiansen See answer to linked question. Yes, it's getting turned into pts but the fact that it's pts gets lost along the way. If I've understood what Mark says correctly.